# How to Add entity to Dictionary Object Initializer?

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to pass html attributes.

It is possible to pack into one expression code some like this?

```
var tempDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> { 
   { "class", "ui-btn-test" }, 
   { "data-icon", "gear" } 
}.Add("class", "selected");
```

or

```
new Dictionary<string, object> ().Add("class", "selected").Add("diabled", "diabled");
```

?

Comment: This does not make sense, use either collection initializer or Add()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is known as method chaining.  A good example of this is the StringBuilder's `Append` method.

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
b.Append("test").Append("test");
```

This is possible because the Append method returns a `StringBuilder` object

```
public unsafe StringBuilder Append(string value)
```

But, in your case, the Add method of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is marked void

```
public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
```

Therefore, method chaining is not supported.  However, if you really wanted to use method chaining when adding new items, you could always roll your own:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> AddChain<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> d, TKey key, TValue value)
{
  d.Add(key, value);
  return d;
}
```

Then you could write the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
  .AddChain("test1", "test1")
  .AddChain("test2", "test2");
```